# What is the difference between flow and eslint in react-native? Which one should I use ? Can I use both?

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I was asked to use static analyser in my project in react-native. As I am already using Eslint , prettier which also help to identify compile time errors and then I found flow for static analysis in react-native.

Its making me confuse as eslint does the similar work.

and I didn't find difference between flow and eslint. so my question is

1. Are eslint and flow solve the same purpose ?
2. if not then when to use eslint and when to use flow
3. Can I use flow and eslint together ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Are eslint and flow solve the same purpose ?

Yes. I think they have same final purpose (it doesn't mean they solve same problem). Help programmers realize the bugs/risky codes that may cause bugs at the typing/coding phase by warning the ugly/wrong-syntax codes. So it will reduce runtime bugs.

> 2. if not then when to use eslint and when to use flow

- ESLint is a linter
  https://eslint.org/docs/about/

  > Code linting is a type of static analysis that is frequently used to
  >   find problematic patterns or code that doesn’t adhere to certain style
  >   guidelines. There are code linters for most programming languages, and
  >   compilers sometimes incorporate linting into the compilation process.

ESLint checks the rules more like convention rules.

- Flow is a static type checker
  https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/

  > Flow is a static type checker for your JavaScript code. It does a lot
  >   of work to make you more productive. Making you code faster, smarter,
  >   more confidently, and to a bigger scale.
  >
  > Flow checks your code for errors through static type annotations.
  >   These types allow you to tell Flow how you want your code to work, and
  >   Flow will make sure it does work that way.

It's a little bit same as ESLint, but focus deeply on type annotations.

- If you want to reduce typo/risky/ugly code in JS at the convention level -> ESLint is required.
- If you want to add sticky type to JS code, and other programmer won't use your code in the wrong way -> Flow

> 3. Can I use flow and eslint together ?

Yes. I'm using @babel/preset-flow and eslint-config-airbnb.

P/s: In my opinion, ESLint is a must have. Flow/TypeScript can be considered

Comment: I think it's pretty confused to say that eslint and flow "have the same purpose." That only holds true in the most general sense, where the purpose of all analysis tools is to help improve the quality of code. That's so general as to not really be useful. The goals of eslint and flow are somewhat overlapping but mostly orthogonal. If they had the same purpose, it is unlikely that you would want to use both tools at the same time. If they have the same purpose, you would likely be choosing between one or the other. eslint is a linter that _might_ catch some possible runtime errors.

Comment: @LyleUnderwood Because JS is an interpreted language. So we can not know if we have a typo or write a wrong syntax line. With compiled language, the complier can help we, but JS doesn't have it. So ESLint and Flow help we know it at the coding time, instead of the error explore at the run-time. Both ESLint, Flow have the same purpose is warning us the errors before the code actually runs.

Comment: @LyleUnderwood They have same purpose don't mean they are same, or they are can replace each other. They help us protect code from different sides. But the purpose still is "catch the bug as more as possible before it goes live".

Comment: "eslint is a linter that might catch some possible runtime errors." -> yes. What do you think what Flow want when he's warning you about the wrong type param?. Also want to catch some possible runtime errors.

Comment: @tuledev JavaScript is not an interpreted language; it's compiled "just-in-time", right before it's run. This may be a largely academic distinction but I think it's important to be precise when discussing programming, just as when doing it.

Comment: @CharlesWood thank you very much. I will search and investigate more about it.

Answer (score 5):

[Flow](https://flow.org/en/) is a type checker for javascript, it ensures that you pass functions or classes the correct type of information, based on information that you provided beforehand before you even run the code.

[ESLint](https://eslint.org) is a linter

> Lint, or a linter, is a tool that analyzes source code to flag programming errors, bugs, stylistic errors, and suspicious constructs.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)

So [ESLint](https://eslint.org) has a long list of prefined rules that you can tweak to your liking that allow you to catch errors, whether it be syntax, code style or bad practices before you run it.

So to conclude each program attempts to solve two different issues, and therefore can be used independently, together, or neither of them.